# Messed up panel. Blank space off right side of xubuntu panel?

Tags: xubuntu, panel

I was playing with my panel options, and somehow, my clock and tray items shifted away from their proper location at the far right of my screen, resulting in this ungainly mess IMAGE HERE. How can this be repaired?

[http://i.imgur.com/fRBfJFD.png](https://i.imgur.com/fRBfJFD.png)

Everything starting with the power icon should be shifted to the right, ending with the clock all the way at the far right of the screen.

Comment: A reboot might solve this, if not I'd create a new panel and delete the old one, it does not need too much time to do that. A nice feature is the `Backup and restore`-function, you should use it.

Comment: As far as using the backup and restore feature, isn't it a bit late for that now? Rebooting did not help.

Comment: backup and restore feature is meant to use in the future. This feature enables you also to switch to different panel-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to panel preferences and edit the separator. You should see an expand box. Select that and it should move the items back to the right.

Comment: That didn't quite get it (there is no option to edit the separator in the preferences pane I showed), but it did put me on the right track. I right clicked where the separator should have been, chose 'Properties', and there was an unchecked 'Expand' option, which I reversed, and my issue was solved. Thanks!